# Colocar emoticons no chat do meu site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html-tags, editor-de-texto

Gostaria de saber como em php ou javascript como colocar emoticons conforme a pessoa digitar o texto e um comando, ex:

**Olá bom dia [/sun]** ou 
**Estou bem [:smile]**

Enfim independente do comando como fazer para que seja substituído por uma imagem no texto seja ela .png ou .gif?

Answer (score 2):

Em javascript você pode fazer assim:

Use [:smile] e [:sad] para gerar os emoticons.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
  $('#input').keyup(function() {
    var emoticonsMap = {
      '[:smile]': 'https://cdn2.macworld.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3595098/smiley_face_thumb.png',
      '[:sad]': 'http://orig14.deviantart.net/ef35/f/2016/036/c/c/sad_emoji_by_catstam-d9qkdaq.png'
    }

    var formatedWord = this.value.split(' ').map(function(word, i) {
      if(emoticonsMap[word]) {
        word = "<img src='" + emoticonsMap[word] + "'>";
      }
      return word;
    });

    $('#result').html(formatedWord.join(' '));
  });
</script>
```

Ele pega o texto toda vez que o usuário digitar alguma coisa nova e faz o mapeamento das palavras separadas por espaço, para adicionar um emoticon novo basta colocar a chave e o link dentro do json emoticonsMap.

====================================================================

**Aqui em baixo está uma forma mais simplificada e que eu acredito que tenha um grande ganho em desempenho comparado ao código de cima em textos grandes:**

Porém nesse caso não podemos usar os colchetes nas keys.*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
  var emoticonsMap = {
    ':smile:': 'https://cdn2.macworld.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3595098/smiley_face_thumb.png',
    ':sad:': 'http://orig14.deviantart.net/ef35/f/2016/036/c/c/sad_emoji_by_catstam-d9qkdaq.png',
  }

  $('#input').keyup(function() {
    var text = this.value;

    $.each(emoticonsMap, function(key, link) {
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), "<img src='" + link + "'>");
    });

    $('#result').html(text);
  });
</script>
```

Ele pega o texto toda vez que o usuário digitar alguma coisa nova e faz um loop com todos os emoticons para procurar e substituir caso encontre.

*OBS.: Tome cuidado ao usar em suas keys elementos que podem ser interpretados pelo RegExp.